# Create NSDictionary for calculating numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to display sections and rows correctly for my `uiTableView`.

I have had great help from one contributor and am fairly close to fixing my issue. The Issue can be seen [here](https://app.io/ozR8w7). Its not far off being right, its just the sections that need to be sorted.

It is repeating the section titles instead of only showing it once. Im not sure exactly how to fix this.

```
// Find out the path of recipes.plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lawpolice" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //Sort the array by section
    self.sortedArray = [self.dataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[
                                                                     [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Section" ascending:YES],
                                                                     [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Title" ascending:YES]]];

    self.temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.sortedArray) {
        NSMutableArray *array = self.temp[dict[@"Section"]];
        // No items with the same section key stored yet, so we need to initialize a new array.
        if (array == NULL) {
            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

        // Store the title in the array.
        [array addObject:dict[@"Title"]];

        // Save the array as the value for the section key.
        [self.temp setObject:array forKey:dict[@"Section"]];
    }

    self.policePowers = [self.temp copy]; // copy returns an immutable copy of temp.

 //Section for sorting
    self.sectionArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Section"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.sectionArray);

    //Title
    self.namesArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Title"];
    //Offence
    self.offenseArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Offence"];
    //Points to Prove
    self.ptpArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"PTP"];
    //Action
   self.actionsArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Actions"];
    //Notes
   self.notesArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Notes"];
    //Legislation
   self.legislationArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Legislation"];
    //PNLD
   self.pnldArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"PNLD"];
    //Image
    self.imageString = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"image"];
```

[image: Plsit]

**titleForHeaderInSection**

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

**numberOfSectionsInTableView**

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return [self.policePowers count];
    }
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *sectionrows = self.policePowers[self.sectionArray[section]];
    return [sectionrows count];
}
```

**Update**

To be clear, if two items have the same Section value, I want to automatically group them into an array and have that array mapped to the Section value at the end

Comment: I'm confused.  A table view is an array, and naturally maps to an NS(Mutable)Array, not an NSDictionary.  It makes far more sense to have an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents the data for one row.

Comment: Maybe my logic is flawed. How would I go about doing it correctly? Section is the KEY.

Comment: Presumably sections are in some order (and, from the table view's standpoint, indexed by a number).  An array is ordered, a dictionary is not.  Consider an array of sections, where each section is a dictionary, and one of the dictionary values is an array containing the rows for that section.  Each element of the array of rows is a dictionary containing all the info for that row.  (There are several minor variations on this scheme, but this is the basic approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:` basically loops through two arrays and maps the object in one array at the current index as the key for the object in the other array at the same index. When you're calling

```
self.policePowers = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:self.namesArray forKeys:self.sectionArray];
```

it therefore maps the items in `self.sectionArray` as the keys for the items in `self.namesArray`. Looking at your plist file, the "Title" keypath (which is mapped to `self.namesArray`) has a value of string, so your `NSLog` results make sense, as `self.namesArray` is an array of strings, not an array of arrays.

I'm not sure how you were supposed to get a result like

```
"Alcohol: Licensing/Drive unfit" = {
     "Drive/attempt to drive/in charge whilst unfit or over",
     "Drive/attempt to drive/in charge whilst unfit or over",
     "Drive/attempt to drive/in charge whilst unfit or over",
 }
```

Where is that array supposed to come from?

-- EDIT --

I don't think there's a concise way to accomplish what you want, so it'd have to be done manually. I haven't actually used `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path]` before, so is `self.dataArray` an array of dictionaries with each item representing one of the items in the plist (Item 44, Item 45, etc)? If so, you could do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.dataArray) {
    NSMutableArray *array = temp[dict[@"Section"]];
    // No items with the same section key stored yet, so we need to initialize a new array.
    if (array == null) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    // Store the title in the array.
    [array addObject:dict[@"Title"]];

    // Save the array as the value for the section key.
    [temp setObject:array forKey:dict[@"Section"]];
}

self.policePowers = [temp copy]; // copy returns an immutable copy of temp.
```

-- EDIT AGAIN --
The app crashes because `self.policePowers` is an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSArray`; thus it doesn't have an `objectAtIndex:` method. If you're trying to get the section title, try this instead:

```
return [self.sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
```

Furthermore, if you're working with a table view, I'd basically have `self.sectionArray` sorted whichever way you like, then whenever I needed to populate data in each section, I would use `self.policePowers[self.sectionArray[section]]` to return the array of titles mapped to that section title.

-- YET ANOTHER --
If you break it up into the following lines, where is the `NSRangeException` thrown? If you `NSLog`, do the results match what you expect?

```
NSString *title = self.sortedKeys[indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = self.policePowers[title];
NSString *value = array[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Ok, Maybe my logic is flawed. How would I go about doing it correctly? Section is the KEY that I need to sort by and populate the uitableheader.

Comment: What's the use case for having "Drive/attempt to drive/in charge whilst unfit or over" three times in an array? Is there supposed to be one for each time that particular string appears as the title?

Comment: sorry Ill explain. I have 50+ items with each item being a NSDictionary. I need to sort by sections which is contained within the  NSDIctionary of each item (as shown in the plist snippet image) as a NSString. That is what I am having the issue with and why I am struggling to dynamically populate the uitableview with the header sections correctly.

Comment: In other words, if two items have the same Section value, you want to automatically group them into an array, have that array mapped to the Section value at the end?

Comment: yeah exactly what i want. Is this possible?

Comment: Nice one. That works. Only issue now is `titleForHeaderInSection` crashes the app when I do this: `return [self.policePowers objectAtIndex:section];` It returns error `[__NSDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` If this keeps going on Ill prob put a bounty on this question!

Comment: So close to working now, I have added a bounty and updated the question above to be clearer. Only 1 small issue remains. There is also a link to the demo in the question now showing the exact issue.

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone Whenever there's a duplicate section, are the keys strings, and are they identical? `NSDictionary` uses `isEqual` when accessing values so it shouldn't even be possible to have duplicate keys like that in an `NSDictionary`; the code above should already group items with the same section value into one array. Also, where and how is `self.sectionArray` declared, and does this issue happen also when running on a device rather than app.io?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for all this help. I think my issue is with how I call `self.sectionArray`. Its NSlog declares all every section as it has not been filtered. I have updated above with how I do it. I am not using self.policepowers which I am sure is my issue.Also it is the same issue on both app.io and device

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone Instead of `self.sectionArray`, have you tried using `[self.policePowers allKeys]` instead? I'm not sure if that would be sorted though, so you may need to sort the resulting array first.

Comment: You my friend are brillant. I did indeed need to sort it after. It wont let me award the bounty yet but I will as soon as it does

Comment: Bounty awarded. If you are 'passing' through I would love to know how to setup the prepareForSeague as it is obviously not calculating the section but only the row. No worries if you can't. Thanks again!

Comment: Assuming you're trying to implement tapping on a `UITableViewCell` to segue to a detail view, you should be able to access the selected `UITableViewCell` through the `sender` parameter of `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Then you can call `[[tableView indexPathForCell:cell] section]` to get the section for the cell.

Comment: Opps sorry, I meant how would I use the section and row to get the `objectAtIndex`. Is it objectAtIndexes?

Comment: I can get the section and row using `indexPath.row` and `indexPath.Section` but don't know how to combine them to get the correct row.

Comment: Remember that `[self.policePowers allKeys]` array you generated and sorted earlier? I'm just going to call it `self.sortedKeys` for reference. To get the object at a given indexPath, you would use `self.policePowers[self.sortedKeys[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row]`. To break this down more readably, `self.sortedKeys[indexPath.section]` gives you the section title (key) for the given index. We use this key to get the array mapped to that key. We then access the string at index `indexPath.row`.

Comment: Feel bad for asking all the time because you have been brilliant but `self.policePowers[self.sortedKeys[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row]` crashes the app with a NSRangeexception error. Trying to pass it so the value of `self.namesArray = [self.sortedArray valueForKeyPath:@"Title"];` can be passed. This is alot harder than I presumed it would be!

Comment: Thanks @kamaros. All sorted now. You are superb! Can't thank you enough :)